# DVDR drive note recognized using 152d:2338 JM20337 Hi-Speed USB

Tags: drivers, usb, dvd

I see the controller in `lsusb` but Ubuntu does not recognize it as a drive.

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp.
/ JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

I installed k3b , that installed some more drivers I guess and it gets recognized.

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

I did install these as well :

```
sudo apt-get install cdftools cdtool
```